# Trying to use FireBase login, can't find packages?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to learn to make apps by making a messenger.  I was adding FireBase login by following the provided google tutorial.  But, I can't seem to do it because I can't find two of the packages I'm told to import.

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth;
```

and

```
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult;
```

Here is my gradle for importing the dependencies and plugins:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

and in the module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
}
```

I have my google-services.json file in the app folder and the gradle successfully syncs.   I searched similar issues but people seemed to be missing dependencies everytime which as far as I can tell I'm not.  Maybe the tutorial has out of date packages but I wouldn't know where to go from there.  Thanks!

Comment: have you updated your sdk?

Comment: I have.  Also, made sure the google play services and repository were included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `build.gradle` for app like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

...
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.  How in the future can I find these things on my own?  Also does it matter if I put the apply plugin at the top or bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you read this line from [Add Firebase to Your Android Project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup):

```
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Try adding this line to the bottom of your `build.gradle` plugin. Currently, I believe you have added to top of `build.gradle`.

Also, from [Firebase Google SignIn Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin):

Add the dependencies for Firebase Authentication and Google Sign-In to your app-level build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.0'
```

Comment: yeah I had it at the bottom before but I moved it to the top in order to show it with the other apply plugin for the question.